# It is possible to "allowfullscreen" when opening a youtube link in an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

My HTML knowledge is very patched together and out of date, so this is probably just a huge mess.

What I have is an iframe called "videosframe" that I have links directing youtube videos into, and I want them to have the youtube fullscreen option.

Currently:

```
<iframe src="source" name="videosframe"></iframe>

<a href="youtubelink" target="videosframe"><img src="youtubethumbnail"></a>
```

And I have several of the youtube links, all same format as the one above.

The target so that the videos open in the iframe works fine, but none of them have the "allowfullscreen" enabled, and I'm not sure how to go about adding it. I'm thinking that I'll have to do something entirely different instead of using links pointing to the iframe, but I'm not sure what is best.

Thanks in advance -

**EDIT:** What I've currently got going on: http://jsfiddle.net/ospqrdta/

Comment: what tests you did? do you have a work in progress?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle to the original post - my latest attempt was to make an iframe with an onclick function to open in the videosframe, but that didn't work. All my work is kind of guesswork though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "allowfullscreen" to the iframe itself fixed this.

...Can't believe I didn't try that sooner.

Comment: Haha, I thought that was too much of a no-brainer so I deleted my comment... glad you got it working!

Comment: Hah yeah thanks!! I'm very new to these sorts of things so all the obvious answers still sometimes come as a shock.